# No list returned by random.shuffle()

Tags: python

I wrote some code in two different ways which I thought were exacly equivalent but I got two very differnt answers:

This first way worked exactly as expected:

```
test_listA = list(range(0, 5))
random.shuffle(test_listA)
print(test_listA)
```

It printed out:

```
[2, 1, 0, 3, 4]
```

But when I reorganised it like so:

```
test_listB = random.shuffle(list(range(0, 5)))
print(test_listB)
```

It prints out:

```
None
```

Why the difference?

Comment: `random.shuffle` works in place.

Comment: I dont understand why this got so downvoted.

Comment: Those two are not the same. In the second case, you assign the result of the function call to the variable, but the function returns `None`. Generally, it is convention for functions or methods that mutate to return `None` (true most of the time with some exceptions like `list.pop`)

Comment: @CeliusStingher This question is downvoted because it already has an answer on SO since 2013.

Answer (score 1):

### The problem

[random.shuffle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) returns `None` and shuffles the original list in place. From the documentation:

> Shuffle the sequence x *in place.*

Assigning the value that `random.shuffle` returns (`None`) back to the shuffled list would set the value of the variable to `None`.

---

### The solution

You can copy the object and work on the copy:

```
import copy
import random


a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = copy.copy(a)
random.shuffle(b)

print(f"a = {a}")
print(f"b = {b}")
```

> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>
> b = [1, 3, 4, 2]

Comment: Could you please add a possible solution aswell? :D

Comment: @CeliusStingher, question contains solution

Comment: Thanks for it @Infinity, now it's crystal clear. +1

Comment: Well, the issue is that it *returns `None`*, since the OP already knows it works in place. It is a convention that a function which mutates its input to return `None` but that isn't necessarily true

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I've edited the answer accordingly :)